# C++: Objects and Arrays/Loops

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

So I was able to create the code to show the different sections with the Color/Letter/Shape. Now I was wondering how I can make it do that I can display an Object 1 and it has 1 color, 1 letter, and 1 shape? For Example, it can display: Object 1: Color  Letter Shape, or something like that? I need to do this for 4 objects. Here is what I have do far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main() {

    string Color[] = { "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Purple", "Yellow",
        "Black", "White", "Orange", "Brown" };

    for (const auto& s : Color) 
        cout << s << '\t'; 

    cout << endl; // endl adds a new line
    cout << endl;
    string Object[] = { "Square", "Triangle", "Circle", "Rectangle", "Oval" };
    for (const auto& s : Object)
        cout << s << '\t';

    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;
    string Alphabet[] = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" };
        for (const auto& s : Alphabet)
            cout << s << '\t';




    return 0;
```

Comment: C++ doesn't provide any portable way to do this. There are ways native to Windows (e.g. see SetConsoleTextAttribute) and Linux (e.g., see ncurses). If you need practical portability, you can probably get by with ncurses on UNIX-like systems, and pdcurses on Windows.

Comment: Perhaps you should start with a book, class, or tutorial on object oriented programming?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have come up with. I was able to cycle through memory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

namespace {
    const std::vector<std::string> COLOR = { "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Purple", "Yellow", "Black", "White", "Orange", "Brown" };
    const std::vector<std::string> SHAPE = { "Square", "Triangle", "Circle", "Rectangle", "Oval" };
    const std::vector<std::string> LETTER = { "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K",
        "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z" };
}


struct Obj {
    std::string color, letter, shape;
};

int main()
{

    Obj obj = { COLOR[0], LETTER[17], SHAPE[3] };

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        std::cout << *(std::string*)((std::string*)&obj + i) << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Output: `RED R RECTANGLE`

Comment: So would I just put this code below the code I already have and it would work?

Comment: I modified my answer to include the full program. And just to let you know, this realistically isn't a great way to do things. Looping through memory like this should be avoided, and I don't see much of a practical use.

Comment: Any ways of putting multiple objects? What other ways would you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create an Object class ( try to give it a more meaningful name ), which has a shape attribute and a letter attribute. This way, each object will have its own properties and it will make this task you want to do much easier !
You will be able to doing something as :

```
Object myObj = new Object("red", "A", "circle");
cout << myObj.color << myObj.letter << myObj.shape << endl;
```

This would display, in this case in the same line and without spaces but you can change that, the object's color , letter and shape.

Comment: I feel like he wanted to use a loop to cycle through the members, as he used loops in his example. If not, then this answer should cover it. He was a bit unclear.